# bootstrap table hide before filtering

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap html table. filtering is used in the field. how do I make sure that the table contents are hidden before filtering starts?
filter script and html table:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#surname").on("keyup", function () {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#table tr").filter(function () {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
</script>
<table class="table" id="table">
    <thead class="thead-light">
      <tr>
           <th></th> 
        <th class="text-center" scope="col">Guest</th>
        <th class="text-center" scope="col">Org</th>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Bootstrap v4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/) uses `d-none` for setting anything to "display: none".

Set each on each `<tr class="d-none">` and they will be hidden on default. In your code, just after you filtered everything, let's show them again using jquery (not tested):

```
    /* ... */
    $("#table tr").filter(function () {
      const show = $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1;
      if (show) {
        $(this).removeClass('d-none');
      }
    });
```

Comment: the script doesn't work. filtered does not support show.

Comment: Jep, that's correct. `filtered` is a boolean. Just as I said: it's untested. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This post is more of a comment on BS-4 than anything....

**Your requirement is very simple - first hide all the tr's and then on the filter - show the ones that meet the requirement.**

Soap box moment -

I am not in favour of the new BS-4 utility classes and use of "**!important**" on everything.... to the casual observer - it may well be nice to simply apply the class to the elemnet and get the outcome - but when you look at the code or the less files from BS **- EVERY SINGLE UTILITY CLASS IS STYLED WITH "!IMPORTANT"....**

this can be seen in the following picture which shows a span with 4 utility classes - and **ALL four classes are styled with the use of !important**..... that alone is enough to make me re-consider BS as a viable option for creating sites - imagine all the important tags that you will have.

I also do not love the new approach of using a utility for every single style choice... imagine a div with 4 different margins styles, four different paddings, and four different border styles..... a utility class for each.... eek

**Just my opinion - but for something as simple as display: none... do it with css and leave off the !important.**

[image]